# TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration. return _initialMessage;

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm writing a contract in remix compiler and I'm facing this issue. Can someone please help me understand What am I doing wrong and why I'm facing an type error when I'm trying to return _initialMessage or for that case new message

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract Inbox{
    string message;

    function _Inbox(string memory _initialMessage) private {
        return _initialMessage;    
    }

    function _setMessage(string memory _newMessage) private{
        return _newMessage;
    }

    function _getMessage() public view returns(string memory){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set variable in _inbox and _setMessage methods.
Change your code to:

```js
    pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract Inbox{
    string message;

    function _Inbox(string memory _initialMessage) private {
        message =  _initialMessage;    
    }

    function _setMessage(string memory _newMessage) private{
        message = _newMessage;
    }

    function _getMessage() public view returns(string memory){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to mention the kind and number of returns expected from a function using returns('the return types').

for eg. in _Inbox function , u just need to include returns(string).